# How to append data table below a plot in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to make a compound plot in matlab, with a data table below. Just like the one in this image (yes, that one was made in excel):

[image]

As far as I go, I'm able to make the plot, but have no idea of how to make the table below. Here's my code:

```
y = [1,4; 0,0; 0,0; 1,0; 4,5; 21,10; 13,9; 3,3; 2,NaN; 0,NaN; 0,NaN; 1,NaN];
z = [16,34; 16,17; 26,17; 27,21; 42,37; 60,45; 45,47; 37,33; 28,NaN; 14,NaN; 
     16,NaN; 21,NaN];

z(z==0) = nan;

aa=max(y);
P= max(aa);

bb=max(z);
q= max(bb);

yyaxis left
a=bar(y,1,'EdgeColor','none');
ylabel('Días');
ylim([0 (P+2)]);

yyaxis right
b=plot(z);
ylim([0 (q+5)]);
ylabel('µg/m³');
b(1).LineWidth = 2;
b(1).Marker = 's';
b(1).MarkerFaceColor = [1 0.5216 0.2];
b(2).Marker = 'o';
b(2).MarkerFaceColor = [0 0.5255 0.9020];
b(2).LineWidth = 2;
b(2).Color = [0 0.4392 0.7529];

XTickLabel={'Enero' ; 'Febrero' ; 'Marzo'; 'Abril' ; 'Mayo' ; 'Junio' ; 
            'Julio' ; 'Agosto' ; 'Septiembre' ; 'Octubre' ; 'Noviembre' ; 
            'Diciembre'};
XTick=[1:12];
set(gca, 'XTick',XTick);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', XTickLabel);
set(gca, 'XTickLabelRotation', 45);
set(gcf, 'Position', [100, 100, 1000, 350])

%Maximizar el espacio de la figura
ax = gca;
outerpos = ax.OuterPosition;
ti = ax.TightInset; 
left = outerpos(1) + ti(1);
bottom = outerpos(2) + ti(2);
ax_width = outerpos(3) - ti(1) - ti(3);
ax_height = outerpos(4) - ti(2) - ti(4);
ax.Position = [left bottom ax_width ax_height];

%%%%%% Grilla %%%%%%%
grid on

legend('Total Episodios 2017','Total Episodios 2018','Conc.Prom. Mensual 
        2017','Conc.Prom. Mensual 2018');


%%% Colores %%%%
barmap=[1 0.4 0; 0 0.4392 0.7529]; 
colormap(barmap);
```

I would deeply appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: You can add tables with the "uitable" in MATLAB. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to make a single figure

Comment: I added an example

Comment: I'd argue that you can create a pixel-perfect copy of that table in MATLAB, there's nothing there that MATLAB cannot draw. But it won't be easy... Also, the horizontal grid lines that Excel makes in plots are so ugly!

Comment: I didn't know you were supposed to exactly imitate the style :) I bet you can make it similar but exactly the same, not easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
figure;

% Plot first part
subplot(2,1,1);
x = [2 3 4 1 2 4 12 45];
plot(x)

% Plot table
ha = subplot(2,1,2);
pos = get(ha,'Position');
un = get(ha,'Units');
ht = uitable('Units',un,'Data',randi(100,10,3), 'Position',pos);
```

[image]